# Why my fix menu in not working smoothly on scrolling.

Tags: javascript

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 5) {
        $('#page-header').addClass('fixed');


    } else {

        $('#page-header').removeClass('fixed');

    }

}).scroll();
```

Why my fix menu in not working smoothly on scrolling. i am using in my moodle theme  frontpage.php or i have to add some thing for smoothness.

Comment: You're modifying the DOM too frequently, as `$(window).scroll` fires multiple times in a single scroll. Consider checking the existence of the `class` before add or remove it.

Comment: @raptor You're advice is good.  How about a code example and turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Raptor Im most mobile browsers the scroll event is only fired after the scroll occurred, not while the user is scroll.

Comment: @null thanks for the note, but OP does not mention about mobile browser. In mobile browser case, since the code only execute once in each scroll event, the performance should be okay.

Comment: @Raptor You are correct, missread `i am using in my moodle theme` as `i am using in my mobile theme`.........................

Comment: haha, doesn't matter. as web developer, we should cater both desktop & mobile browsers.

Comment: Click on the link to open http://alis28.demo.moodlethemes.com

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the DOM too frequently, as `$(window).scroll` fires multiple times in a single scroll. Consider checking the existence of the class before add or remove it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 5) {
      if(!$('#page-header').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('#page-header').addClass('fixed');
      }
    } else {
      if(!$('#page-header').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('#page-header').removeClass('fixed');
      }
    }
});
```

also, I removed an extra `.scroll()` call at the end of the script.

---

Alternatively, you can make use of a [jQuery On Screen plugin](http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/) which will add a pseudo class `:onscreen` with the div visible in the browser. Codes are as follow:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($("#page-header").is(':onScreen')) {
        console.log("Element appeared on Screen");
        if(!$('#page-header').hasClass('fixed')) {
          $('#page-header').addClass('fixed');
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Element not on Screen");
        if(!$('#page-header').hasClass('fixed')) {
          $('#page-header').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }
});
```

See if the plugin fits your needs.